# Using Javascript to change style of elements in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I have a problem with javascript in PHP. I want to use Javascript function to change ccs atribute **display** to **block** for only those **div** elements that contain certain text that is in **php variable** which is taken from column in **MySQL table**. I don't know if it is actually possible this way but here's the code:

PHP:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM Filter1";
  $result=$conn->query($sql);
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $meno=$row['meno'];
  echo '<script type="text/javascript"> filterTovar() </script>';
```

JavaScript:

```
   function filterTovar()
  {
    var meno='<?php echo $meno; ?>'; 
    var produkt=document.getElementsByClassName("tovar");
    produkt.style.display="none";
    for(var i=0;i<produkt.length;i++)
    {
      produkt[i].style.display="none";
    }
    for(var i=0;i<produkt.length;i++)
    {
      if(produkt[i].innerHTML==meno)
      {
        produkt[i].style.display="block";
      }
    }
  }
```

I am trying to make some kind of filter that makes only certain divs shows depending on result of table but the code above doesn't work and I'm not sure if it is possible to make work this way.

MySQL table I'm taking data from:

```
    id      meno        znacka      cena    op      format
    425     H81M-S2V    GIGABYTE    46.03   DDR3    mATX
    426     H110N       GIGABYTE    83.05   DDR4    mITX
```

**EDIT:** Better explanation of my problem: User uses checkboxes to filter products on my website, in database php creates table with corresponding products. My code above is supposed to take that table and use column "meno" in which is name of product to show only those div that contain string "meno".

**EDIT2:** I want to ask if it is possible to change or work with elements css via DOMDocument(). If yes it would answer my question.

Comment: Can you add the database structure to your question?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a better explanation of what *"depending on result"* means with regard to what gets hidden

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but there is no need to use javascript/jQuery - just use HTML and CSS.

Basically, you have your database result set and you loop through it with a while loop, right?

I guess you are constructing HTML in that while loop.

In each iteration of the loop, test your MySQL column value and add a class to the desired HTML element.

Here is an example:

```
$out = '<table><tbody>';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $theclass = ($row['something']=='hideme') ? ' hiddenTD' : '';
    $out .= '<tr><td class="' .$theclass. '">' .$row['something']. '</td></tr>'
}
$out = '</tbody></table>';
echo $out;
```

Of course, you would have CSS defined in the document, like:

```
<style>
    .hiddenTD{display:none;}
</style>
```

This is a terrible example because you can't "hide" a TD, but it's an example.

Comment: Well, I don't need to use table, I need to change css of elemenets that contain that column.

Comment: I think I worded it poorly. I have like 7 div elements with same class "tovar". What I'm trying to do in JavaScript is picking ALL elements with class "tovar" and than testing them 1 by 1 in the loop if they contain column. If they do, change div's style.display to "block" otherwise do nothing.

Comment: There is something I don't understand here. How do you get the HTML elements in MySQL results? Are you storing a chunk of HTML in a MySQL table? Where does all that HTML get created?

Comment: No, I'm not storing HTML anywhere, I have created table manually that contains strings that are inside of those div elements.